# SQL Server : what is best datatype to store MD5 hash?

Tags: sql-server, hash, md5, uniqueidentifier, binary-data

I need to store in SQL Server a list of items uniquely identified by a hash.

In C# I compute my hash as MD5 hash of concatenation of the item ids ( `Guid` ).

Currently, my hash has datatype `byte[]` in C# , and `binary(16)` in SQL Server.

Here's the DDL :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemSet](
    [GUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [HashCode] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
    [Item1GUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Item2GUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    ...
    [UtcModified] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [ItemSet_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

But perhaps I am better with :

```
[HashCode] [uniqueidentifer] NOT NULL,
```

`uniqueidentifier` is also 16 bytes and perhaps SQL Server offers performance or other advantages for `uniqueidentifier` over `binary(16)` ?

In C# the corresponding datatype is `Guid` and apparently there's a special `Type 3 Guid` form when calculated from an MD5 hash :

```
nnnnnnnn-nnnn-3nnn-xnnn-nnnnnnnnnnnn
```

where `3` indicates `Type 3` , and the `x` byte is masked to `10xx`.

But it's not clear to me how to create such a `Type 3 Guid`.  And for my purposes it seems artificial & unnecessary to utilize a special format datatype.

Is there any optimal/accepted standard for working with MD5 hashes in C# and T-SQL ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I store a hash in a SQL Server database using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252794/how-can-i-store-a-hash-in-a-sql-server-database-using-c)

Comment: [Check out this very thorough answer on dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126446/is-there-a-penalty-for-using-binary16-instead-of-uniqueidentifier)

Comment: note this is not a duplicate of posts asking whether to store hash in db character vs numeric datatypes.  i'm not asking about `char(n)` `varchar` `nchar(n)` `nvarchar`.